# I got infinity loop after creating one modal for all buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three buttons with different content and one modal, which I want to use after clicking on the button, and change the content. But after reloading my page, I got infinity loop in function, where I set true on view Modal. Can you help me, where is the issue?

First I created a state for my data and then I have functions, where I set state. And after a click on the button, I pass individual data (header, body) to showModal function with these data. But it is not working, I got infinity loop in showModal and I don´t know why.

```
 let header = null;
 let body = null;

 const [modal, setModal] = useState({
    modalHeader: '',
    modalBody: {},
    modalStatus: false
 });

    const showModal = (header, body) => {
      setModal({
        modalHeader: header,
        modalBody: body,
        modalStatus: true
      });
    };

  
    const hideModal = () => {
      setModal({
        modalHeader: '',
        modalBody: null,
        modalStatus: false
      });
    };




return(
<div>
      <Modal
        show={modal.modalStatus}
        onCancel={hideModal}
        header={modal.modalHeader}
        footerClass="modalAction"
        footer={
          <React.Fragment>
            <Button inverse onClick={hideModal}>
              BACK
            </Button>
          </React.Fragment>
        }>
        <div className="backgroud-graph">
          <h2 className="center">{modal.modalHeader}</h2>
          <Pie data={modal.modalBody} />
        </div>
      </Modal>


      <Button onClick={showModal(header="Cards" , body={dataYellowCardsCoop} )}>
        Porovnanie kariet
      </Button>

      <Button onClick={showModal(header="Tackles" , body= {dataTacklesCoop})}>
        Porovnanie obrannych zakrokov
      </Button>

      <Button onClick={showModal(header="Goals" , body= {dataGoalsCoop})}>
        Porovnanie golov
      </Button>


</div>
);
```

Comment: Isn't "infinity loop" the name of an Avengers movie? Or is it where the Apple campus is?

Comment: Could you please add the entire component code? It might be in a part you did not share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the handler, you need to pass a function, not call it, as you do here:
`onClick={showModal(header="Cards" , body={dataYellowCardsCoop} )}`
In your case, when the component is rendered the showModal function is called.
Additionally, you pass arguments incorrectly (you don't need an equal sign and their names).

```
<Button onClick={() => showModal("Cards", {dataYellowCardsCoop})}>
   Porovnanie kariet
</Button>
```